# Add Sweet Alert popup to button in React component

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, sweetalert

I found this perfect Sweet Alert module for Bootstrap and React (which I'm using in my Meteor app):

http://djorg83.github.io/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/

But I don't understand how you include this code inside a React component.

When someone clicks the Delete button in my app, I'd like a Sweet Alert prompt to pop up asking for confirmation.

Here is my component for the Delete button:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Goals from '/imports/collections/goals/goals.js'
import SweetAlert from 'react-bootstrap-sweetalert';

export default class DeleteGoalButton extends Component {

  deleteThisGoal(){
    console.log('Goal deleted!');
    // Meteor.call('goals.remove', this.props.goalId);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="inline">
          <a onClick={this.deleteThisGoal()} href={`/students/${this.props.studentId}/}`}
          className='btn btn-danger'><i className="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete Goal</a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And here is the code that I copied from the Sweet Alert example:

```
<SweetAlert
    warning
    showCancel
    confirmBtnText="Yes, delete it!"
    confirmBtnBsStyle="danger"
    cancelBtnBsStyle="default"
    title="Are you sure?"
    onConfirm={this.deleteFile}
    onCancel={this.cancelDelete}
>
    You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!
</SweetAlert>
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Working example based on your code http://www.webpackbin.com/VJTK2XgQM

You should use `this.setState()` and create `<SweetAlert ... />` on `onClick`. You can use fat arrows or `.bind()` or any other method to be sure that proper context is used.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SweetAlert from 'react-bootstrap-sweetalert';

export default class HelloWorld extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      alert: null
    };
  } 

  deleteThisGoal() {
    const getAlert = () => (
      <SweetAlert 
        success 
        title="Woot!" 
        onConfirm={() => this.hideAlert()}
      >
        Hello world!
      </SweetAlert>
    );

    this.setState({
      alert: getAlert()
    });
  }

  hideAlert() {
    console.log('Hiding alert...');
    this.setState({
      alert: null
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: '20px' }}>
          <a 
            onClick={() => this.deleteThisGoal()}
            className='btn btn-danger'
          >
            <i className="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete Goal
        </a>
        {this.state.alert}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for the quick and thorough response, @hinok Much appreciated!

Comment: @hinok how can i parsing messsage by variabe there, i just put variable and got an error

Comment: @FreddySidauruk What variable and where you'd like to use it? Where do you want to pass it?

Comment: @hinok how can you use this with Redux? Does this work with props? I want to use it as a callback from my action  creator.

Comment: @Juanjo You should put only serializable data in redux store so regular boolean flag should work in such case. Dispatch an action that set property like `showAlert` to `true` and in your `connected component`, take `showAlert` from redux store and display `SweetAlert` using condition in `JSX`.

Comment: @hinok I used this code and it works. The only problem is buttons appear as grey no matter how I change `confirmBtnBsStyle`. Any idea why I can't change style of buttons?

Comment: @MustafaChelik Your problem seems strictly related to CSS / styles issue and it's hard to help in such case, without knowing how styles as a part of your application is built.

Comment: @hinok `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";` solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

if it doesn't work for someone the way you exposed the @hinok solution then you can modify this function like this:

```
deleteThisGoal() {    
this.setState({
    alert: ( <
        SweetAlert success title = "Woot!"
        onConfirm = {
            () => this.hideAlert()
        } >
        Hello world!
        <
        /SweetAlert>
    )
});
```

};

This was the code that I wrote:

```
showAlert(title, message, callBack, style) {
    this.setState({
        alert: (
            <SweetAlert 
                warning
                showCancel
                confirmBtnText = "Sí"
                cancelBtnText = "No"
                confirmBtnBsStyle= {style ? style : "warning"}
                cancelBtnBsStyle = "default"
                customIcon = "thumbs-up.jpg"
                title = {title}
                onConfirm = {callBack()}
                onCancel = {this.hideAlert}
            >
                {message}
            </SweetAlert>
        )            
    });
}

hideAlert = () => {
    this.setState({
        alert: null
    });
}

updateCustomer = () => {..."a few lines of code here"}
```

This was the called from button:

```
{<Button color="primary" disabled={this.state.notChange} onClick={() => this.showAlert('Save changes for client', '¿Are you sure?', () => this.updateCustomer, null) } >Save changes</Button>}
```

Saludos!!