# SweetAlert2 not showing up

Tags: reactjs, popup, alert, sweetalert2

I am using react-js in my project.

```
const SweetAlert = require('react-sweetalert2');

const Updater = React.createClass({
<div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
  <a onClick={() => this.deleteThisGoal()} className="btn btn-danger"> <i className="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" />
    Delete Goal
  </a>
  {this.state.alert}
</div>

deleteThisGoal: function() {
  const getAlert = (
    <SweetAlert success title="Woot!">
      Hello world!
    </SweetAlert>
  );

  this.setState({
    alert: getAlert
  });
}
});
```

When I inspect the element the value gets assigned to `this.state.alert` but when I click on the alert no popup shows up.

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I referred [Add Sweet Alert popup to button in React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006087/add-sweet-alert-popup-to-button-in-react-component) for the example.

Updated my answer with:

```
const SweetAlert = require('react-sweetalert2');

const Updater = React.createClass({
render(
<div>
<div style={{ padding: '20px' }}> <a  onClick={this.deleteThisGoal}  className='btn btn-danger' > Delete Goal </a>
</div>
    {this.popup}
</div>
);
},

deleteThisGoal: function() {
  this.setState({
    show: true
  });
},

  popup: function(keyword) {
        return (
             <SweetAlert 
             show={this.state.show} title="Deleted goal" text="Goal was deleted!"
             onConfirm={() => this.setState({ show: false })}>
             </SweetAlert>
        );
    }

});
```

still no alert that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `const SweetAlert = require('react-sweetalert2').default;`